# php: get the name of an inheriting class in a static method

Tags: php, static-methods, late-binding

Okay, the post title might be a little confusing.

I have this code:

```
class A {
    public static foo() {
        return get_called_class();
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

class C {
    public function bar() {
        echo B::foo();
    }
}
```

Output: C

WHat I want to get in foo() is the class name of B. How can I do this without changes in the class B?

Regards,
Jan Oliver

PS: __ CLASS __, get_class() are not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: get classname from static call in extended class.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506705/php-get-classname-from-static-call-in-extended-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before PHP 5.3, this is not possible without hacks and is known as late static binding, a googleable term.

If you're interested, here is the SO article with answers: [Faking Late Static Binding before php 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890505/faking-late-static-binding-before-php-5-3)

Comment: I read the docs of php, but I didn't find a solution for my problem, for I don't want to change the B class.

Comment: As I mentioned, if you're using php lower than 5.3 it's not possible without the hacks I provided: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890505/faking-late-static-binding-before-php-5-3/1554813#1554813

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the built-in **[Reflection class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getname.php)** for that.