# Is it possible for a parent to use a child's constant or static variables from inside a static method?

Tags: php, oop

Below is an example of what I'm trying to do. The parent can't access any of the child's variables. It doesn't matter what technique I use (static or constants), I just need some kind of functionality like this.

```
class ParentClass
{
    public static function staticFunc()
    {
        //both of these will throw a (static|const) not defined error
        echo self::$myStatic;
        echo self::MY_CONSTANT;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 1;
    public static $myStatic = 2;
}

ChildClass::staticFunc();
```

I know this sucks, but I am **not using 5.3**. Any hacky solution that involves eval is more than welcome.

Comment: See answers to "Faking late static binding before php 5.3": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/890505/faking-late-static-binding-before-php-5-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: The < 5.3 requirement was added after the response was written. In this case, a hacky solution exists with [`debug_backtrace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php). Have fun.

And, just to be sure... I suppose `echo ParentClass::$myStatic;` is out of question. Again, I struggle to find a use case for this. It's certainly esoteric to find such a static method that would **only** be called using another class. It's a kind of bastardized abstract method.

ORIGINAL:

Yes, with [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php):

```
<?php
class ParentClass
{
    public static function staticFunc()
    {
        echo static::$myStatic;
        echo static::MY_CONSTANT;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    const MY_CONSTANT = 1;
    public static $myStatic = 2;
}

ChildClass::staticFunc(); //21
/* the next statement gives fatal error: Access to undeclared static
 * property: ParentClass::$myStatic */
ParentClass::staticFunc();
```

I would say it's not a great design though. It would make more sense if ParentClass also defined the static property and the constant.

This feature was introduced in PHP 5.3.

Comment: Note that static binding has been implemented in PHP 5.3

Comment: @nuqqsa I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Before 5.3 you can use this to get the constant:

```
constant(get_class($this) . '::CONSTANT_NAME')
```